# TFS 2018 API: Can access workitems but not workitem API end point

Tags: c#, tfs

I created a middleware app that will pull work item data from TFS.

I was able to do this using the workitems end point.

http://sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.0/workitems?ids=1,2,3

Now, I also need to get the work item links per work item. Per docu I would need to access the workitem with expand items. But unfortunately, work item end point does not seem to work.

http://sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.0/workitem/3

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The end of the working query has "?ids=1,2,3" which are parameter for the query.  The non working query has "/3" which is think is wrong.  It need to look similar to first query with a question mark and then the parameters.

Comment: as per documentation the format is different

Comment: Every server is different..We cannot help without the documentation.  Best to contact the vendor support.  The format of the request is bad and each server request are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, looks like you just want the URL of created WorkItem, so that anyone when click on URL, created Work Item will be Open.

```
https://tfsurl:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PatrickProject/_workitems/edit/172/
```

The URL should be above format and here DefaultCollection is the collection name and the PatrickProject is the project name. I used this url and got rid of the id '172' in this case and use the ID of newly created work item. This would return the URL to go to the work item HTML page.

So it's a fixed format, if you have Newly Created WorkItem ID and collection name , project name, you just need to follow above format and change the last value of work item ID. That's it , ignore of which work item type you created.

If you want do this with code, do not use Rest API, you need to use client API, sample snippet:

```
var tfsURI = new Uri("http://test:8080/tfs");
var networkCredential1 = new NetworkCredential("test", "test!");

    ICredentials credential = (ICredentials)networkCredential1;
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(credential);
    VssCredentials vssCredentials = new VssCredentials(winCred);

    using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsURI, vssCredentials))
    {
        collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
        TswaClientHyperlinkService hyperlinkService = 
           collection.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();
        String TFSurl = hyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(17648).ToString(); //17648 WorkItem ID
    }
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: im accessing this info through c# code. i get a json data from http://sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.0/workitems?ids=1,2,3

Comment: @TheProvost Yes, if you use Rest API to directly return a single work item
`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1` However this will only get a url to the json data for the work item created, not the URL of the HTML page of the bug. Such as below output that I got
`https://tfsurl:8080/_apis/wit/workItems/workitemID`
When I load the above link in browser, I also got JSON data, instead of the HTML page for the work item  created. What you got, cause you are using  Rest API or **Rest Client call from C#**.

Comment: According to your description, using `sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/` this will return json data, not HTML link. It's an expected behavior. You need to use another  kind of API. Client libraries for Azure DevOps and TFS.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi Patrick. unfortunately this project was already created when we came in. They were not using the nuget library to connect to the api thus this will cause a significant amount of work to update. For now we used the suggestion of Etienne but accepting your answer since this is probably the reccomended way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific work item information you need to use the [Get Workitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API call so try http://sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/workitems/3?api-version=4.0 instead.

You can also use this http://sampleserver:8080/tfs/sampleproject/_apis/wit/workitems/3?$expand=Links&api-version=4.0 and this will return the work with Id of 3 and all it's links (parent, attached files, changetset, etc.)

Notice that the api-version=4.0 with change depending on the version of TFS/Service you are using and should always be the last string in the REST call.